# Cloud Identity Platform Test API

Tags: google-identity

The rest API (https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api) support user sign up without request attribute, multiFactor : {enrolledFactors :[]}. It seems that the only way to enable multi-factor authentication is via NodeJS server as described here: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/manage-mfa-users.

Is this correct? NodeJS api must be relying on rest-api. So any reason, it will not work with a direct rest API call.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, the restful API does let a client programmatically specify MFA attributes. The API is accounts.signUp.

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signUp